# MSSQL Geography column - Sweref99

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I have a table containing a LocationEast and LocationNorth columns(int).
LocationEast and LocationNorth are coordinates that follows the SWEREF99 standard.

According to this page, http://www.epsg-registry.org/, the SRID for SWEREF99 is 3006.

I then try to run the following code:

```
INSERT into Places(Name, LocationEast, LocationNorth, GeographicLocation) values ('My Location', 673318, 6580874, geography::STGeomFromText ('POINT(673318 6580874)', 3006))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
.
The statement has been terminated.
```

My question is: How do I use the SWEREF99 format?

Comment: You probably are supposed to use the `geometry` data type, not the `geography` - `geometry`::STGeomFromText ('POINT(673318 6580874)', 4977)). Also, you probably want SWEREF99TM? Then it's 3006.

Comment: Aah, thank you! It works now! :) Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert a feature, you would need to use `geometry` spatial type because your coordinates are defined in a projected coordinate system. The `Sweref99` coordinate system you refer to is probably is `sweref99tm` which has epsg code of `3006`.

So, it will be:

`geometry::STGeomFromText ('POINT(673318 6580874)', 3006))`